# CSS - Position footer relative to body's bottom

Tags: css, position, css-position

I might me using the terms absolute and relative wrong, but hopefully you get what I mean. I want to give my footer some "bottom: 10px" so that it stays at the bottom of the page, no matter if the page's content is more or less than 100% of the browser window. I tried positioning it absolute but it will be positioned relative to the browser window then, not the body.

This is an example: http://public-demo.webflow.com

Any ideas? Thank you :)

Comment: add 'position: relative' to the body and 'position: absolute' to the footer

Comment: I think you may be looking for a sticky footer - give that a google

Comment: @zimt28 please confirm what response is good

Comment: @AndrewMatthew's answer did it :) Sadly I can't confirm the comment

Comment: I shall make it as an answer for you to confirm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to the body

```
position: relative
```

and add this to the footer

```
position: absolute
```

This way the footer will be positioned accordingly to the body

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
.footer-text {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
    bottom: 10px;
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Your new edit will keep the footer in A POSITION and not FIXED to it. Try Scrolling with a large content.

Answer (score 0):

> **FOOTER TO STICK BOTTOM IF CONTENT IS SMALLER THAN THE VIEWPORT and BEHAVE NORMAL IN OTHER CASE**

---

You'll need a tiny JS for that.

```
$(function () {
    var bht = $('body').height();
    var wht = $(window).height();
    if (bht < wht) {
        $('#footer').css("position", "absolute");
        $('#footer').css("bottom", "10px");

    }
});
```

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3N4L9/4/

> **FOOTER TO STICK TO BOTTOM IN ANY CASE**

---

This will generate same output as required :

Like page 1 : http://jsfiddle.net/3N4L9/1/

Like page 2 : http://jsfiddle.net/3N4L9/2/

It'll keep footer on the bottom of page irrespective of content and scroll.

```
.fixedFooter{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you set the bottom to 0px.

If you want to fix this kind of problem, you can inspect your element with Mozilla, and play your code there.